# How can I convert `JSON.Element` to `JSON` with "SwiftyJSON"?

Tags: swift, swift4, swifty-json

I want to do like below. How can I convert `JSON.Element` to `JSON` with "SwiftyJSON"?

```
public func convert() -> String? {
    let json :JSON = ["Animals" : ["dog","cat"], "Shop":"Tokyo"]
    let animals = json["Animals"]
    let repezentativeAnimal = animals.first
    repezentativeAnimal!["Shop"] = json["Shop"] // Value of tuple type 'JSON.Element' (aka '(String, JSON)') has no member 'subscript'

    // I want to return String below
    //  ["dog":"---", "Shop":"Tokyo"]
    return repezentativeAnimal.rawString() // error : Value of type 'JSON.Element?' (aka 'Optional<(String, JSON)>') has no member 'rawString'
}
```

Comment: I might help you on this stuff, but may you explain better what would you like to achieve? returning such string: `["dog":"---", "Shop":"Tokyo"]` it's quite meaningless

Comment: You say `I want to return String ["dog":"---", "Shop":"Tokyo"]` but even after fixing your code it would not return this, it would only return "dog". Your question is unclear. You can see this if your replace `let repezentativeAnimal = animals.first` by `var repezentativeAnimal = animals.first!.1` ...

Answer (score -1):

pod Install

> pod 'Alamofire-SwiftyJSON'

and import your VC

> import SwiftyJSON
>
> import Alamofire_SwiftyJSON

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: install pod file then import SwiftyJSON and import Alamofire_SwiftyJSON your ViewController